# htaccess: 404 RewriteRule not working for specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This should be a simple task: Send a 404 redirect for a specific URL: /folder1/folder2

Here's what I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/(.*)$ /folder1/folder2/$1 [R=301,L] (works, but I want a 404)
RewriteRule ^/?folder1/folder2 - [R=404] (does not work)
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2 - [R=404,L] (does not work)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/folder2
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404] (does not work)

RedirectMatch 404 folder1/folder2(.*)$ (does not work)

RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2(.*)$ /not-found.html [L,R=404] (does not work)

# This works, but is not what I need:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /not-found.html [L,R=404]
```

When testing the rules (http://htaccess.mwl.be/) they work as expected, but not on my localhost. What is going on?

I'm running Apache 2.4.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: After deconstructing my htaccess I found that all rules after the 404 redirect rule are still processed. Is there a way so say "if this 404 rule is met, stop processing the remainder of the htaccess file"?

Comment: only R=3xx does redirect. It's well documented. The `RedirectMatch` requires url as a 3rd parameter.